# How do i make my Embed work?

Tags: embed, discord

I need help with my embed
Could someone check over this for me? I cant find the problem and it won't tell me what the problem is.

```
const discord = require("discord.js");

const TOKEN = "PRIVATE TOKEN";
const PREFIX = "-("

var bot = new discord.client();

bot.on("message", function(message) {
    if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;

    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

    var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")

    switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {
        case "embed":
            var embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
                .setDescription("Hello, This is an Awesome ");
            message.channel.sendEmbed(embed);
            break;
        default:
            message.channel.sendMessage("Invalid Command!")
    }
});

bot.login(TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just as easy to send a message with the embed inside of it, *rather* than using RichEmbed (for me anyway).

---

### Using Embeds *Without* RichEmbed

```
message.channel.send({embed: {
    title: "Hello!",
    description: "this is an awesome embed!"
}});
```

[^ This is what that looks like! ^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUHD3.png)

You may also find [this handy little tool](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/) useful, it lets you see a **live version** of your Embed **before** you copy it over to your bot, meaning a lot less testing and fixing.

Again though, I haven't used RichEmbed, but this is a more-than-easy compromise.

Comment: Another Reference to Help with Discord.JS in General:
https://anidiotsguide.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/examples/using-embeds-in-messages.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need help with embeds, look [here](https://anidiots.guide/examples/using-embeds-in-messages.html) for a full explanation on how to use both regular and RichEmbeds from AnIdiotsGuide.

https://anidiots.guide/examples/using-embeds-in-messages.html

> [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) [discord](/questions/tagged/discord) [discord.js](/questions/tagged/discord.js)